# 404 page not found error. Custom Page

Tags: magento2, custom, page

I am trying to create custom page page having error 404.

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="SimpleMagento_Custom" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Controller :-**

```
<?php

namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class DisplayInfo extends Action
{
    protected $_pagefactory;
    public function __construct(PageFactory $pagefactory,Context $context)
    {
        $this->_pagefactory=$pagefactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pagefactory->create();
    }
}
?>
```

**Layout file (hello_test_displayinfo):-**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="SimpleMagento\Custom\Block\EmployeeData" name="new_layout1" template="SimpleMagento_Custom::Employee.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

**Block file:-**

```
<?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Block;

class EmployeeData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        echo "YES..!";

    }
}

?>
```

**Employee.phtml:-**

```
<h1>you have created new page </h1>

<h3><?php $block->getName();?></h3>
```

Comment: Please update your `etc/frontend/routes.xml` file's content in your question.

Comment: Not anything you're missing here. Can you please update your question with file path ? May be something wrong is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please correct your file path with below structure

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/registration.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'SimpleMagento_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SimpleMagento_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="hello" frontName="hello">
            <module name="SimpleMagento_Custom" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/Controller/Test/DisplayInfo.php

```
<?php

namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Controller\Test;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class DisplayInfo extends Action
{
    protected $_pagefactory;
    public function __construct(PageFactory $pagefactory,Context $context)
    {
        $this->_pagefactory=$pagefactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pagefactory->create();
    }
}
?>
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/Block/EmployeeData.php

```
<?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Block;

class EmployeeData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        echo "YES..!";

    }
}

?>
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/view/frontend/layout/hello_test_displayinfo.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="SimpleMagento\Custom\Block\EmployeeData" name="new_layout1" template="SimpleMagento_Custom::Employee.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/view/frontend/templates/Employee.phtml

```
<h1>you have created new page </h1>

<h3><?php $block->getName();?></h3>
```

**URL :**

http://www.example.com/hello/test/displayinfo

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Calling wrong route.
call

```
 hello_test_displayInfo
```

URL :

```
 hello/test/displayInfo
```

Comment: @Akash Check , my asnwer is it works?

Comment: seems like doesn't matter. Its running with both names.Problem was location of controller.

Comment: @AkashKilledar ok, Thanks Good luck